# Knockout TypeScript table not rendering data

Tags: javascript, typescript, knockout.js

I have a table, which shows invoices, then a nested table that shows the individual checks made for those invoices. I'm using knockout and typescript to render these tables.  I am able to get the invoices to show, however the checks table doesn't show the data. Here's the code so far:

```
<tbody class="nohighlight" data-bind="foreach: parent.bankDrafts">
                            <tr>
                                <td><span data-bind="text: CheckID"></span></td>
                                <td><span data-bind="text: CheckRunID"></span></td>
                                <td><span data-bind="text: VendorName"></span></td>
                                <td><span data-bind="text: CheckDate"></span></td>
                                <td><span data-bind="text: FormatCurrency(CheckAmount)"></span></td>
                                <td><span data-bind="text: Globalize.formatCheckRunApproveStatus(ApprovalStatusID)"></span></td>
                             </tr>
                        </tbody>
```

Here's the typescript:

```
namespace CheckRunApproval {
declare let searchParameter: string;

class SearchCheckRunModel {
    public searchParameter = ko.observable<string>(searchParameter || null);
    public checkRuns = ko.observableArray<CheckRunModel>(null);
    public bankDrafts = ko.observableArray<BankDraftInfoModel>();
}
 var model = new SearchCheckRunModel();

export function GetBankDrafts(data: CheckRunModel): void {
    CheckRunServiceMethods.GetBankDrafts(data.CheckRunID())
        .done(bankDrafts => ko.mapping.fromJS(bankDrafts, null, model.bankDrafts));
 }
}
```

And here's the service call:

```
public static GetBankDrafts(checkrunID: number): JQueryPromise<BankDraftInfo[]> {
        return CommonMethods.doAjax<BankDraftInfo[]>(
            "/Corp/Checks/CheckRunApprovalWS.asmx/getBankDrafts",
            JSON.stringify({ checkrunID }),
            "GetBankDrafts"
        );
    }
```

Now the server call does reach the server side code, passing in the correct parameters and returning the list of checks I'm trying to show as part of the invoice.  However, the table itself does not have any data.

[image: Printchecks]

My thinking is that it has something to do with the way I'm mapping the model to the view model. It could also be the way I've setup the table itself, with the correct knockout attributes, etc. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: changing parent.bankDrafts to $parent.bankDrafts() it fixed the issue.

Comment: dont you mean `$parent` instead of `parent` in `foreach: parent.bankDrafts` ?

Comment: You can always debug what is the VM in the view by such trick: <span data-bind="uniqueName: console.log($date, $parent, [any var u want])"></span>

Comment: By adding changing parent.bankDrafts to $parent.bankDrafts() it worked. Thanks everyone.

Comment: I've added it as an answer then, u can accept it as resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your code. Use `$parent.bankDrafts` instead of `parent.bankDrafts` in a foreach binding.